# Convert Xlxs file to Csv using Phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have a problem here, I want to upload Excel file to convert into CSV.
After submitting, my code only creates Csv file with **empty data** on it, (blank rows). Here is what I wrote:

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

// get the upoloaded file
$excelFile = $_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"];

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($excelFile);

// write into csv
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Csv");
$writer->save("upload-file.csv");
```

Comment: I also share the excel file to upload https://easyupload.io/hfiex4

Comment: Why not use Excel itself for the convert?

Answer (score 0):

You should use for the writer

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);
$writer->setEnclosureRequired(false);

$writer->save("upload-file.csv");
```

Read more in [the documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/)

Comment: @collie-it-anne-k-frey I tried to put your suggestion, but is not working and setEnclosureRequired() seems to unrecognized.

**It shows** `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv::setEnclosureRequired()`